# "ubuntu" shows up in boot menu, but my laptop keep telling me that "No OS detected"

Tags: boot, system-installation, lvm

I tried to intall ubuntu 13.10 on my Acer Aspire 4750 yesterday, and I think I make a mistake choosing that "LVM" option.

Now I am facing these :

1. "ubuntu" option now shows up in my boot menu. What is that? Why is it there? I have install ubuntu before on another notebook, but I never saw that before.
2. How can I remove it or at least make my notebook boot ubuntu automatically? I can`t boot ubuntu without selecting that first on boot menu. And I have to access boot menu by pressing F12 when booting.

[image: Options]

I have tried to reinstall it, but it still there.
This is my : Boot-Repair pastebin : http://paste.ubuntu.com/6931555/

Answer (score 2):

That photograph is from your BIOS boot media menu. It detects some device - USB stick, another hard disk, or something - with name "ubuntu" on it. It says `No OS detected`, as that is not your hard disk.

You should choose "HDD 0: WDC..." option, if you installed the Ubuntu to your hard disk.

Comment: I am sure I have nothing named "ubuntu".

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you don't have any personal data on the laptop, right?

If this is the case, boot from ubuntu live cd or usb and select "Try Ubuntu". Once Ubuntu 13.10 loads, click on the Dash menu, and type "disks". Right Click on the computer's HD and chose "delete partition". Once it's done, close the disks app and go to your live cd's/usb's desktop. Click on the "Install Ubuntu" option and an the 3rd screen of the installation (the one where we chose the HD we want the OS to be installed) your first choice will be "Erase disk and install Ubuntu".

This will basically format your disk and install Ubuntu properly, leaving the essential spaces (like swap and boot load). (If you chose disk for installation manually you had to leave swap space and boot loader space on the HD).

Please let me know about any queries there might come up :)

Comment: I will try it right now. :)

Comment: I've done it, but nothing changed. Should I go with manual setting?

Comment: Is this a newer UEFI system? With secure boot. If secure boot is on only secure boot systems will work. Also some only boot UEFI if UEFI switch is on or only boot BIOS if BIOS switch is on. And you may have installed in the other mode, so it does not see it correctly. Post link to this report:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I spent hours last night looking at my bios setup. I found nothing like "secure boot" , "UEFI" or anything like that. I am downloading Boot-Info right now.

Comment: this is my boot-repair pastebin http://paste.ubuntu.com/6931528/ i will try the recommended repair option

Comment: update http://paste.ubuntu.com/6931555/

Comment: You have a gpt partitioned drive now with one ext4 partition and no boot files. It does not look like anything is installed. Ubuntu will install to a drive with gpt partitioning and boot with BIOS or UEFI if correct support partitions are there. But Windows will only boot from gpt with UEFI. Best to totally reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and I fixed it:

Main -> Network Boot -> F12 Boot Menu: [Enabled]

Save & exit

On next startup, hit F12, and I was presented with Windows or Ubuntu. Selected Ubuntu and it started right up.